# Поиск в истории в сеансе PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

В линуксовых терминалах есть поиск по истории, вызываемый нажатием <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Существует ли аналог в PowerShell?

Comment: Поправлю: <Сtrl>+<R> есть не в "линуксовых терминалах", а в bash. В "голом" sh (который "из коробки" является шеллом в, например, FreeBSD, и который советуют использовать в shell-скриптах для максимальной переносимости кода) такой фичи нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть, вызывается тем же самым <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск вперед по истории - <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

У меня 10-ка, не уверен, есть ли этот функционал в более старых версиях. Но его точно можно доставить через

```
Install-Module PSReadline
```

вместе с подстветкой и другими плюшками: [The Search for a Better PowerShell Console Experience](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/16/the-search-for-a-better-powershell-console-experience.aspx)

UP: `Install-Module` - это [сниппет из PsGet](http://psget.net/):

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
```